# Density function

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a distributed uniform random variable on the interval $(0, 1)$ and $Y$ an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda =1$. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, compute the density function of $Z=X+Y$

I've done this so far:
We know that $X$ is distributed uniformly in $(0,1)$ so we have 3 cases on $f_X(x)$.:

If $x<0 \Rightarrow f_X(x)=0$.

If $0\leq x\leq 1 \Rightarrow f_X(x)=1.$

If $x>1 \Rightarrow f_X(x)=0.$

And we want $f_Z(z) = \int f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)$ but I don't know which limits to take on the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$f_X(x)= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 1}~~~\\f_Y(y)=\mathrm e^{-y}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y} $$

> And we want $f_Z(z)=\int_? f_X(x)\,f_Y(z−x)\,\mathrm dx$ but I don't know which limits to take on the integral.

It's given by the supports.   You thus require $0\leqslant x\leqslant 1$ and $0\leqslant z-x$, because those are the supports for $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(z-x)$.   Elsewhere the product will vanish.   You also know that $0\leqslant z$ will be the support for $f_Z(z)$ (because $0+0\leqslant X+Y$).

So that gives $0\leqslant x\leqslant\min\{1,z\}$ for any $0\leqslant z$, which you can partition at $z=1$.

Which leaves you with the integrals in each part of this piecewise function.

$$\begin{align}f_Z(z) &= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z<1}\int_{0}^z \mathrm e^{-(z-x)}\,\mathrm d x+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant z}\int_{0}^1 \mathrm e^{-(z-x)}\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=\begin{cases}0&:&z<0\\[1ex]1-\mathrm e^{-z}&:&0\leqslant z<1\\[1ex](\mathrm e-1)\,\mathrm e^{-z}&:& 1\leqslant z\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$f_Z(z)=\int f_X(x)f(z-x)dx=\int_0^{z} e^{-(z-x)}dx=1-e^{-z}$ for $0<z<1$ and   $f_Z(z)=\int f_X(x)f(z-x)dx=\int_0^{1} e^{-(z-x)}dx=e^{-z}(e-1)$ for $z>1$

[The conditions to be met by $x$ are $0 <x<1$ and $0<z-x <\infty$]